# tail not providing output in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, awk, serial-port, tail

i have written a bash script that will filter 'tail' output, which the entire command

```
 tail -f /var/log/asterisk/messages | awk 'match($12, /[^0-9]91([0-9]{10})@default/, a) {print a[1]}'
```

works fine from the CLI but not when placed in the bash script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 phonenumber=$(tail -f /var/log/asterisk/messages | awk 'match($12, /[^0-9]91([0-9]{10})@default/, a) {print a[1]}')
 echo "$phonenumber >> test.log"
```

which doesn't output anything, (2135551234, is the expected output string) i have tried writing to the log file and writing just the stdout but neither work.

i have tried the script using 'cat' instead of 'tail' and that works fine. but i dont want to dump the output of the entire file, hence the use of 'tail'.

I have also tried using 'tee' but to no avail

the end goal of this script with be to send the phone number as it comes into the PBX to a serial device to another system and used as the CID.

thanks for all your help in advance

Comment: `tail -f` never exits.

Comment: @Barmar you should expand your comment (explain what's happening) and post it as an answer.

Comment: @JimGarrison Way ahead of you

Comment: and you've wrapped your call to `tail` inside command-substitution with `$( tail -f ... )`. So the command has to complete before you it can close the subshell that was started and return what ever was printed. Sorry, but I think you'll have to rethink your design. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
phonenumber=$(tail -f /var/log/asterisk/messages | awk 'match($12, /[^0-9]91([0-9]{10})@default/, a) {print a[1]; exit}')
```

Your version doesn't work because `tail -f` and `awk` are in an infinite loop. Adding `exit` to the `awk` script terminates the loop when the first phone number is found. `awk` exits immediately and its output is put into the variable, and `tail -f` gets a SIGPIPE signal when it tries to write the next line to the pipe, which causes it to exit.

Comment: `@Barmar` Thanks that was spot on